# BAD SuperBlock on Drive

Tags: linux

During a DD command I somhow lost a drive and now it will not mount becouse of a bad superblock. Any sugestions to get this drive working again. Dont need any thing on it just need it working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need anything on that filesystem why not just do an 'mkfs' on it and make a new filesystem? Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/